# Orbits of a descending chain of subgroup actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Suppose a countable group $G$ acts transitively on a countable set $X$. Let $G = G_0\supset G_1\supset\cdots$ be a descending chain of finite index subgroups. Suppose $x,y\in X$ lie in the same orbit of $G_i$ for all $i$. Must they lie in the same orbit of $\cap_i G_i$?

What if we assume that the stabilizer of $x$ is cyclic? Or that $G$ is residually finite? The case I’m particularly interested in is when $G$ is $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ acting on the set of cusps $\mathbb{Q}\cup\infty$.

Comment: Hello. Sorry if this is well-known, but what do you mean by "the stabiliser of $G_i$ is cyclic"? What is the stabiliser of a subgroup? Is it the normaliser/centraliser? I think a counterexample for the first part is $\Bbb Z \supset 2\Bbb Z \supset 4\Bbb Z \supset \dotsb$, for example with the action of $\Bbb Z$ on $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ by addition.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen sorry, I meant the stabilizer of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If I have calculated correctly, then the infinite dihedral group $\langle x,y \mid y^2 = (xy)^2=1 \rangle$ has infinite descending chains of finite index infinite dihedral subgroups with trivial intersection, for example
$$\langle x,y\rangle > \langle x^4,y \rangle > \langle x^{16},yx^5\rangle > \langle x^{256},yx^{21}\rangle > \langle x^{1024},yx^{277}\rangle > \cdots $$
If $G$ acts on the $2$-element set $\{a,b\}$ with $x$ fixing and $y$ interchanging $a$ and $b$, then $a$ and $b$ are in the same orbit of each subgroup in the chain, but clearly not of their intersection.